# How to not export jobs from Oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, database-administration

on the database 10g we have both jobs created with the deprecated DBMS_JOB (select * from all_jobs;) and created with the new DBMS_SCHEDULER (select * from all_scheduler_jobs;).
Is there a way to distinguish between the two kinds of jobs when exporting the whole database from production to test instances? Or anyway a way to not export only some particular jobs?

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script to disable all jobs in Oracle (DBMS\_JOB package)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586051/script-to-disable-all-jobs-in-oracle-dbms-job-package). You could set the job_queue_processes to 0 before importing and then disable the jobs. That way it's not needed to exclude them from the export.

Answer (score 0):

## To Exclude DBMS_JOB:

During export :
expdp ... EXCLUDE=job
During import :
impdp ... EXCLUDE=job

## To exclude DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs

Create a parameter file with:

exclude=procobj:"IN (SELECT NAME FROM sys.OBJ$ WHERE TYPE# IN (47,48,49,50,66,67,68,69,71,72,74))"

Then execute Data Pump Export:

expdp ... parfile=expdp.par